# What will happen if I feed a device with two legs from the same phase?

Tags: electrical

What will happen if I feed a 208v baseboard heater with two legs from the same phase?  What will happen if I feed anything that requires two legs with the same phase?

Answer (score 1):

It will simply not work. You need two different phases/legs to get 208/230/240V.

How in the world could you even do this though? 208/240V circuit would require a two-pole breaker so theoretically you cannot wire these circuits with two wires on the same phase.

Comment: Under stand, I removed the @-pole breaker out of the equation because I am curious as to an actual result.  NEC aside, what would happen?

Comment: Not much. Two hots from the same leg will have minimal voltage across them, mostly from what else is putting load on that circuit.

Comment: Two hots on the same phase should have NO voltage across them, but will have voltage to ground/neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage is measured as a difference between two conductors. So if both conductors are the same phase and same voltage from ground, then the effective voltage to the appliance will be 0 volts and it won't turn on. This doesn't mean that the device wouldn't be electrically "hot" since the conductors still have a voltage relative to ground (so you can still electrocute yourself if you touch the wrong thing). And it's possible that some features of the appliance will work if they are configured to run off of a single hot conductor to a neutral, this is often seen with control panels. But any components of the appliance that require 208V will simply not work.

Comment: I asked this because of a discussion at work, back in my apprenticeship, I worked under this Journeyman who was having trouble with a 208v baseboard heater, the heater would trip the breakers upon closing.  His boss and another Journeyman came in to help.  They came to the conclusion that both legs were the same phase, they made the adjustment with the breakers (yes, it was not a 2-pole breaker) and it resolved the issue and the heater worked just fine.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble believing this unless the solution was to wire it across two different breakers on opposite poles... in which case, ***ugh***, you've just created a situation where someone can turn off a breaker and still get zapped.

Comment: I understand your concern by wiring this without the use of a 2-pole breaker, which I am not responsible for, but this seemed to fix the situation.  I am confused as to why the breaker was tripping in the first place?

Comment: With some old 2-pole FPE and GE skinny breakers it was possible to incorrectly install them across two stabs of the same phase. I also have trouble believing that doing this would trip a breaker where installing it correctly would make the heater work. To my knowledge there is no way this could be possible simply due to the breaker position.